# Active Record query array of Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a json column *(is an array of objects)* in my db containing the many **categories** related to a product like this:

```js
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Category X"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Category Y"
 },
 ...
]
```

I need to translate into active record query the following PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM products p, json_array_elements(p.category) as data
WHERE data ->>'name' = 'Sport';
```

Some of queries that I tried:

```rb
sports = Product.where("category ->>'name' = ?", "Sport")
```

Which returns an empty array (It is wrong since I have records with Sport category in my db)

```rb
sports = Product.where("category @> ?", [{name: "Sport"}])
```

Which raises: `TypeError: can't quote Hash`

```rb
sports = Product.where("category @> ?","{name: 'Sport'}")
```

Which raises: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @> unknown`
and the Hint: `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

So I tried:

```rb
sports = Product.where("category @> ?", "[{'name': 'Sport'}]")
```

and

```rb
sports = Product.where("category @> ?", "[{'name': 'Sport'}]".to_json)
```

and some other queries all without success.

These links: 
[PostgreSQL functions-json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)
[active record querying](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html)
didn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're getting a `PG::UndefinedFunction:` exception ("*operator does not exist: json @> unknown*") is because the @> operator is meant to be used in jsonb data type columns, and your `products.category` column isn't.

For that you can; or to update the data type of the `category` column, or to explicitly cast the column at the moment of performing the query:

```
Product.where('category::jsonb @> ?', [{ name: 'Sport' }].to_json)
```

This:

```
Product.where("category @> ?", "[{'name': 'Sport'}]")
```

isn't going to work, since it's not valid syntax.